# android: LinearLayout cannot be cast in TextView

Tags: android

i wanted to use a specific textfont and implementet the following class:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> names) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, names);
}

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, int textViewResourceId, List<String> names) {
super(context, layoutId, textViewResourceId, names); 
}

public TextView getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(
        getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/calibri.ttf");
    v.setTypeface(tf);
    return v;
    }

public TextView getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v = (TextView)super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(
            getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/calibri.ttf");
    v.setTypeface(tf);
    return v;
    }

}
```

it worked very well (i used the first constructor), but then i changed the layout from textView to a linearLayout, which contains a textView. Therefore i used the second constructor. But then i get the error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

I tried using the original ArrayAdapter instead of my customized one and that worked, although i don't have my font, of course. How can i use this one?

Comment: you have two explicit cast to TextView. Check the content of the layout you are providing as parameter to the super

Comment: If you are using `Eclipse` this can also be caused by some changes you made on the order of creation of the elements in your layout. Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: got it working without this custom arrayAdapter. But when i click on the spinner to open the dropdown menu i get the error:
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

and

```
TextView v = (TextView)super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
```

because you assume that the returned layout is a TextView, which is wrong, since it's a LinearLayout, who doesn't inherit from TextView, so it cannot be cast to it.

In order to get this working, you could try something like this:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private int mTextId = 0;
        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> names) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, names);
        mTextId = textViewResourceId;// remember it, so we can find the real TextView
        }

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, int textViewResourceId, List<String> names) {
        super(context, layoutId, textViewResourceId, names); 
        mTextId = textViewResourceId;// remember it, so we can find the real TextView
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View cell = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            setFontForChild(cell);
            return cell;
            }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View cell = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            setFontForChild(cell);
            return cell;
            }

        private void setFontForChild(View layoutCell)
        {
            View realTextView = layoutCell.findViewById(mTextId);
            if(realTextView instanceof TextView)
            {
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                    getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/calibri.ttf");
                ((TextView)realTextView).setTypeface(tf);   
            }
            //else realTextView is null or is not a TextView.
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:

Looking at the [ArrayAdapter source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java), I've figure it out that the problem is that your `spinner_dropdown_item.xml` doesn't contain a view with the `spinner_item_textView` id, because both `spinner_item.xml` and `spinner_dropdown_item.xml` are considered (by the `ArrayAdapter`) to have a similar structure. So in order to solve your issue, you have 2 options:

1) modify your `spinner_dropdown_item.xml` so it can contain a container(`LinearLayout`) and your TextView as child (don't forget to set the `android:id="@+id/spinner_item_textView"` on your `CheckedTextView`)

2) modify your spinner_item to have only the `FonTextView` (you could set your image using the `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image1"`) and provide 0 for the `textViewResourceId` in the `MyArrayAdapter` constructor. This is a more efficient solution, because it doesn't require additional `LinearLayout` views to be instantiated.

Comment: ok this works, but it gives me the same problem as in the comment above: when i try to open my dropdowmenu i get
 java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)

Comment: Can you show the adapter's constructor call and the xml provided as layout?

Answer (score 0):

code snippet where i call the adapter:

```
public void setupUnits(Set<UnitDescription> descriptions) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    unitDescriptions = new UnitDescription[descriptions.size()];
    unitDescriptions = descriptions.toArray(unitDescriptions);

    for (UnitDescription unit : unitDescriptions) {
        if (unit.getName()!=null) {
            names.add(unit.getName());
        }           
    }

    if (names.isEmpty()) {
        return; 
    }


    MyArrayAdapter adp = new MyArrayAdapter(StartActivity.this,
            R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.spinner_item_textView, names);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adp); 
}
```

spinner_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@layout/spinner_item"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
    <de.schunk.schwenk.util.FontTextView
        android:id = "@+id/spinner_item_textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/spinner_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

spinner_dropdown_item.xml (soll später auch ein LinearLayout werden, wenn möglich):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textColor="@color/spinner_text" />
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should edit your question, and delete this post, since I think it's not quite an answer.